# Android map v2-Get marker position on marker click

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

How to get marker item position on marker click just like in ListView's itemclick?

ok i got the answer

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("onInfoWindowClick method calling and marker position is "+marker.getPosition());

    String title =marker.getTitle();

    for(int i=0;i<CommonUtilities.CoffeeShop_array_list.size();i++){
        String s =CommonUtilities.CoffeeShop_array_list.get(i).Title;

        if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
            **marker_position** = i;
            System.out.println("position of marker - "+marker_position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is noting like positions for a marker I am afraid! Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

This may help you

```
                mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
                          new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {

                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                arg0.hideInfoWindow();
                                double dlat =arg0.getPosition().latitude;
                                double dlon =arg0.getPosition().longitude;
                                String slat = String.valueOf(dlat);
                                String slon = String.valueOf(dlon);
                            alert.showpickAlertDialog2(PlacesMapActivity.this,slat , slon, arg0.getSnippet());  
                            }
                          }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code for get location from marker:-

```
LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myMarker.getPosition().latitude,myMarker.getPosition().longitude);
```

try it.