# Get longitude and latitude of marker on google maps android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, latitude-longitude

In my app the user can onLongClick add a marker to google maps. It saves these coordinates as a point. I know that with the location = location.getLastKnownLocation the methods getLongitude() and getLatitude() can be used. Is there anyway to do this with a marker placed on google maps by the user so that the coordinates can be retrieved. This is the code that gets the marker point and stores it.

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());             map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString())); 
pointfinal = point;
Toast.makeText(this, point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you asking.  I assume you looking for the getLongitude() getLatitude() for the marker that got added on the map right ?  If so, LatLng point is already there for you to use.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());        
    //Create a marker object
    Marker myMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

    //And now you can use it's values
    myMarker.getPosition().latitude;
    myMarker.getPosition().longitude;
}
```

If you have multiple markers you can use an array to store all of them

Comment: JustWe, do you mean point.latitude and point.longitude? 
CarlosJiminez it is given an "AssignmentOperatorExpression" error on these lines myMarker.getPosition().latitude; myMarker.getPosition().longitude;

Comment: Exactly what I meant. point variable has it all you needed here

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077040/android-map-v2-get-marker-position-on-marker-click)

It says

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
    new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.hideInfoWindow();
        double dlat =arg0.getPosition().latitude;
        double dlon =arg0.getPosition().longitude;
        String slat = String.valueOf(dlat);
        String slon = String.valueOf(dlon);
        Log.d("Position","Lat:"+slat+",Lon:"+slon);  
    }
});
```